# Docker driver for Openstack

Tags: docker, openstack

I am working on a OpenStack installation but I cant get it to work with Docker. Without Docker it seems to work, but when I try to start an instance, I get an exception that no host is available. I found out that at my computing nodes the Docker driver cannot be found:

```
2014-04-21 10:51:26.114 1629 ERROR nova.virt.driver [-] Unable to load the virtualization driver
2014-04-21 10:51:26.114 1629 TRACE nova.virt.driver Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-04-21 10:51:26.114 1629 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/virt/driver.py", line 1299, in load_compute_driver
2014-04-21 10:51:26.114 1629 TRACE nova.virt.driver     virtapi)
2014-04-21 10:51:26.114 1629 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/importutils.py", line 52, in import_object_ns
2014-04-21 10:51:26.114 1629 TRACE nova.virt.driver     return import_class(import_str)(*args, **kwargs)
2014-04-21 10:51:26.114 1629 TRACE nova.virt.driver   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/openstack/common/importutils.py", line 28, in import_class
2014-04-21 10:51:26.114 1629 TRACE nova.virt.driver     __import__(mod_str)
2014-04-21 10:51:26.114 1629 TRACE nova.virt.driver ImportError: No module named docker
2014-04-21 10:51:26.114 1629 TRACE nova.virt.driver
```

This is very strange to me because the Docker driver has been suggested in the manual:
http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/config-reference/content/docker.html
Although I cannot find it in the GIT:
https://github.com/openstack/nova/tree/master/nova/virt

Also a variety of sites suggest this driver in their tutorial. I am running the new Icehouse and I've got Docker installed on the local machines. Do you guys have any thoughts? Please let me know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Docker Driver for Openstack Nova has been removed.

"The docker compute driver does not currently have CI running against
it.  In accordance with our plan to require this for all drivers, we
are now removing the driver from nova." :

https://review.openstack.org/#/c/79740/

The docker driver is now located in Stackforge :

https://github.com/stackforge/nova-docker

Answer (score 1):

Please check you have installed docker-py by using below command:

```
pip install docker-py
```

Since you are installing for Icehouse, actually current nova-docker-driver can only support for Kilo release.
Below is my experience installing in Juno for your reference.
Please download the version of nova-docker-driver in below(Sep. 17 released)

```
git clone https://github.com/stackforge/nova-docker.git

cd nova-docker/

git checkout -b pre-i18n 9045ca43b645e72751099491bf5f4f9e4bddbb91
```

This way can help you to use a previous release to support an older OpenStack.

[More complete information](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/12/28/experimenting-with-openstack-sahara-on-docker-containers).